# Loadmore Javascript/jquery is not working in firefox but works in EDGE/CHROME

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I tried below code earlier and it was working fine but now I'm applying the same code on another site but it is not working in Firefox but works in EDGE & chrome.

Can anybody please help what can be the problem in this?

This is for linux server running MySQL 5

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() == ($(document).height() - $(window).height())) {
    var total_pages = parseInt($("#total_pages").val());
    var page = parseInt($("#page").val()) + 1;
    if (page <= total_pages) {
      load_more_data(page, total_pages);
    }
  }
});

function load_more_data(page, total_pages) {
  var catid = "<?php echo $one  =   mysqli_real_escape_string($dba, $_GET['catid']); // Category ID ?>";
  var subid = "<?php echo $two  =   mysqli_real_escape_string($dba, $_GET['subid']); // Sub Category ID ?>";
  var subids = "<?php echo $three   =   mysqli_real_escape_string($dba, $_GET['subids']); // Sub Category 2 ID ?>";

  $("#total_pages, #page").remove();
  $.ajax({
    //url: 'getresult.php?catid='+catid+'&subid='+subids+'&subids='+sub2ids+'&subidss='+sub3ids,
    url: 'subcat3_all_getresult.php',
    type: "POST",
    data: {
      page: page,
      catido: catid,
      subido: subid,
      subidso: subids
    },
    beforeSend: function() {
      $(".loader").show();
    },
    complete: function() {
      $('.loader').hide();
      if (page == total_pages) {
        $(".loader").html('<hr style="border: 2px black solid;"><h2><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle" style="color: red;"></i> No More Results <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle" style="color: red;"></i></h2><hr style="border: 2px black solid;">').show();
      }
    },
    success: function(data) {
      //$('.loader').show();
      if (page == total_pages) {
        $(".loader").html('<hr style="border: 2px black solid;"><h2><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle" style="color: red;"></i> No More Results <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle" style="color: red;"></i></h2><hr style="border: 2px black solid;">').show();
      }
      $("#output").append(data);
    },
    error: function() {
      $(".loader").html("No data found!");
    }
  });
}
```

It is an automatic Load More on scroll down which should work in Firefox same as it works in EDGE or CHROME.
It Does Not show the result in Firefox but in EDGE & CHROME.

Comment: What part doesn't work exactly?

Comment: @Cue in console it is saying `jQuery is not defined` & `$ is not defined`

Comment: There's your problem. How are you loading jQuery? local or CDN?

Comment: @Cue loading locally

Comment: In Firefox, navigate to the Network tab within devtools and filter by JS. Does the local jQuery file appear in the list? If not, the file is not being loaded.

Comment: yes the file is there

Comment: Is it loading before or after any JQuery code?

Comment: it is loading at first

Comment: The code you’ve demonstrated is fine, we know it’s not the problem. We’ve also established that JQuery is undefined. For reasons unknown without seeing the page itself we can only make assumptions that can go on forever. So you’ll want to figure out why jQuery isn’t defined. Unless you can provide some meaningful preview.